# How can I filter by id and type in javascript with filter?

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'SOLD'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'REVIEWS'
  }
...
];
```

I want to remove an object in it by id and type. How do I do that?

this code removes all...

```
if(type === 'SOLD') {
    return draft.filter((el => el.item.id !== notification_id));
 } else {
   return draft.filter((el => (el.item?.id !== notification_id)));
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to remove by either sold or ID you are going to get that deleted as you have duplicate id.

Comment: `arr.filter(n=>(n.type=='REVIEWS'))` Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you cold easily do it with a filter function evaluating both parameters at the same time.
Please have a look at the example below:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'SOLD'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'REVIEWS'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'SOLD'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'REVIEWS'
  }
];

const filterData = (array, id, type) => array.filter(e => e.id !== id || e.type !== type)


const filteredArray = filterData(arr, 1, 'SOLD')
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: I think he is aiming for `e.id === id` otherwise nice solution